# Why is there no Jacobian in the definition of the surface integral, $\iint_UfdS = \iint_Df(r(s,t))|r'_s \times r'_t|dsdt$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition, surface-integrals, parametrization, jacobian

I'm extremely confused by Jacobians and when to use them and I think my lack of understanding can be boiled down to this question:

> Why is there no Jacobian in the definition of the surface integral:
>   $$\iint_UfdS = \iint_Df(r(s,t))|r'_s \times r'_t|dsdt$$
>   where U is some surface and D is another surface?

Isn't $U$ a surface like any other? Don't we need to compensate for the area when going from $U$ to $D$? Has it got something to do with that $U$ is a "function surface"(?) and D is a surface in $R^2$?

Comment: There is no transformation of variables here. That's why there's no Jacobian.

Comment: @Cauchy But let's say I've got $U: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and the parametrization $(s,t) = (2\sin{s}\cos{t}, 2\sin{s}\sin{t}, 2\cos{s})$. Why isn't there a change of variables?

Comment: I shouldn't have said that. Rather, I should've said: that's the definition. Do you understand how it came about? It's not difficult to understand it. If you do, you won't be confused why there's no Jacobian.

Comment: The Jacobian of $r$ is a $3 \times 2$ matrix and the minor determinants of that matrix give the components of $r_s' \times r_t'$.

Comment: ofc you need to compensate, that's why the factor $|r_s'\times r_t'|$ is there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$U$ is a surface in $3$-space, whereas $D\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ is the parameter domain of $U$ in the $(s,t)$-plane. In this plane we have the natural "surface element" ${\rm d}(s,t)$, that just measures ordinary euclidean area. There is indeed a scaling factor between ${\rm d}(s,t)$ and the corresponding area element ${\rm d}S$ on $U$. This scaling factor appears explicitly in your formula, it is $|{\bf r}_s\times{\bf r}_t|$. In other words: To a tiny rectangle in $D$ of area ${\rm d}(s,t)$ corresponds a tiny parallelogram on $U$ of area $|{\bf r}_s\times{\bf r}_t|\>{\rm d}(s,t)$.

The *Jacobian*, on the other hand, is the analogous local scaling factor if we  compute a volume integral over a three-dimensional domain $\Omega$ in "geometric" three space by parametrizing $\Omega$ using some nice domain $D\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ in an auxiliary parameter space. In this situation we have an essentially bijective $$f:\quad D\to\Omega,\qquad(u,v,w)\mapsto \bigl(x_1(u,v,w), x_2(u,v,w), x_3(u,v,w)\bigr)\ ,$$
and then have to compute the Jacobian $J_f(u,v,w)={\rm det}\bigl(df(u,v,w)\bigr)$.